# How to make 2 forms same height, also using an alert for one of forms

Tags: html, css

I have one parent div that contains two divs in wrappers, also the second div has an alert and a two-line label, when the window is stretched, label hat turns into only one line, I would like to make them the same height, but I don’t know how it is to do.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper-item">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="form-label">Short name</label>
      <div class="form_item">
           <input maxlength="30" type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper-item">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="form-label">Long Name Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur</label>
      <input maxlength="30" type="text" class="form-control">
      <div class="form-message">
         Description message Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I used flex to align, if the text is too large for the label, but after adding the alert everything breaks.

Unfortunately, I don’t have the opportunity to change the HTML or use JS, also I can’t change the positioning of the alert to absolute, also it does not make sense to use a static value, if I need to added the text in label and it will be in 3 columns, it will just break the form.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/pzcn7b3w/) you can view an example.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: so you want both `wrapper-item` to be in same height, Do u use bootstrap..?

Comment: @sanoj lawrence sorry but not quite, I need the label component to have the same height, unfortunately i'm trying not to use bootstrap.